# Navigation bar with drop-down menu is not sticky-ing

Tags: javascript, css, menu, sticky

The navigation menu is not 'freezing' to the top of the page while I scroll sticky this navigation menu at the top of the page.

```js
let nav_toggle = document.querySelector('.nav_toggle');
let nav_toggle_icon = document.querySelector('.nav_toggle ion-icon');
let nav_menu = document.querySelector('.nav_menu');

nav_toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav_menu.classList.toggle('active');
  nav_toggle_icon.setAttribute('name',
    nav_menu.classList.contains('active') ? 'close-outline' : 'menu-outline'
  );
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

:root {
  --primary: #7F56D9;
  --secondary: #F4EBFF;
  --text-primary: #101828;
  --text-secondary: #667085;
  --badge-bg: #ECFDF3;
  --badge-text: #027A48;
  --white: #fff;
  --dropdown-bg: rgb(252, 253, 251);
  --shadow: rgba(32, 7, 65, 0.14);
  --container: 124rem;
  --nav-height: 7rem;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

ion-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: 500;
}

a.logo {
  color: rgb(9, 2, 114);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h4:hover {
  color: #eba714;
}

h3:hover {
  color: #3d3d3d;
}

.container {
  max-width: var(--container);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  opacity: 0.98;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: var(--nav-height);
  position: relative;
  background: var(--white);
}

.nav_list {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.nav_action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.nav_link,
.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-primary);
}

.btn-primary {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: var(--white);
  background: var(--primary);
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0.6rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.nav_toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.nav_toggle ion-icon {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: var(--text-primary);
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--nav-height);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--dropdown-bg);
  box-shadow: 0rem 0.2rem 0.5rem var(--shadow);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.nav_list_menu:hover ion-icon {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.nav_list_menu:hover .dropdown {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 102%, 0 102%);
}

.item-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 3rem 0;
}

.item-list-info {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.info-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 0;
  background: var(--badge-bg);
  padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: var(--badge-text);
}

@media (max-width:730px) {
  .nav_toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav_menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--nav-height);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--dropdown-bg);
    display: none;
  }
  .nav_menu.active {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav_list {
    display: block;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav_link {
    padding: 0 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .dropdown {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 0;
    text-align: start;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav_list_menu:hover .dropdown {
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  }
}

@media (max-width:365px) {
  .logo-img {
    width: 10rem;
  }
  .btn,
  .btn-primary {
    padding: 0.4rem 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a class="logo"> RA </a>


      <li class="nav_list nav_list_menu">
        <a href="#!" class="nav_link">
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <div class="dropdown-item">


              <h3 class="item-heading">Menu</h3>

              <div class="item-list">
                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Home</h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item-list">
                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>About</h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item-list">
                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Blog</h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item-list">
                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Get in touch</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="dropdown-item">
              <h3 class="item-heading">Projects</h3>
              <div class="item-list">

                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Carbon Calculator</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-list">

                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Price my car</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-list">

                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Coffee Finder</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-list">

                <div class="item-list-info">
                  <h4>Quran Whiteboard</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

I have tried to attach the 'position: sticky;' and the 'top: 0;' to the container, navigation, etc., and to no effect. I am fairly new to JS and just getting back into HTML and CSS, your help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `li` are supposed to be inside `ul` or `ol`. Also, you didn't close all your elements

Comment: Thank you for noticing this. I am now closing my elements, and going to fix this li issue and see if that fixes the problem.